# Access to AWS Elastic Load Balancer using AWS SDK for python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

So I'm using boto3 to connect to AWS and manage my web server instances which are behind an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB). The problem is that I do not have access to my ELB, it is while I have access to the other existing resources like Instances. For example, while I'm running this piece of code, I can see my running instances:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-east-2")
instances = ec2.instances.all()
for instance in instances.all():
     print(instance)
```

The output is like this:

```
ec2.Instance(id='i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
ec2.Instance(id='i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
ec2.Instance(id='i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

By running the below code, I expect to see my ELBs:

```
elb = boto3.client('elb', region_name="us-east-2")
elbs = elb.describe_load_balancers()
print(elbs)
```

But the output is like this:

```
{'LoadBalancerDescriptions': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'f813b2d3-b5e8-11e7-8b34-73b6f3d263a2', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'f813b2d3-b5e8-11e7-8b34-73b6f3d263a2','content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '335', 'date': 'Fri, 20 Oct 2017 22:49:45 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

As you can see in the output, there is no ELB in `LoadBalancerDescriptions`, while according to the [API refference](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elb.html#ElasticLoadBalancing.Client.describe_load_balancers), it should contains the name of existing ELBs. But I have an ELB in my console that works fine:

[image: The existing ELB in my AWS console]

I do not know why the python code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class ElasticLoadBalancingV2 for the newer load balancers: ALB and NLB. Example: client = boto3.client('elbv2')

Use the class ElasticLoadBalancing for the "Classic Load Balancer".

[ElasticLoadBalancingv2](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html)